# Can we extend OPENAM session time by a specific time period?

Tags: openam, forgerock

I have an application which uses OPENAM authentication mechanism. I have written custom logic to implement session idle time. I want to extend my session time by a specified time period (lets say 10 min, 20 min etc) but currently it is just resetting to default configured time which is 30 minutes for our case.

I need help with APIs that can be used to achieve the same. Also, if you could explain the current behavior about why it is resetting session time to default 30 minutes?